# How to send Java objects that are not defined structures in Thrift

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, thrift

Is there a way to send Java objects that are not defined in thrift files as a structures from one java application to another java application via thrift.
The problem is that we are using an external library that has it's own domain model and we need to send those models via thrift, so is there any techniques of doing this?

Any advices are warmly appreciated.

**UPDATE #1**

Answer below explains correctly possible solutions, currently we are thinking to create our own domain model that mirrors external library classes (it is small enough to put such effort)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Exchange serialized entities as binary data

That's a simple three-step process:

1. serialize the data, e.g. into a `ByteBuffer` or the like
2. send that data through the Thrift interface by means of `binary`
3. deserialize the bytes received into Java entities

The service could be as simple as

```
service MyCoolService {
   binary Foobar( 1: binary javaBytes)
}
```

### A word of warning

It should be mentioned that this breaks the whole idea of a cross-language system which Thrift stands for. Your binary data are only understand by Java programs. You have been warned. But on the other hand, if your use case is that way, the API is only internally used and this aspect will not become an issue, it is a legitimate solution.

### Alternative solution

Another solution could be to miror the domain model with Thrift IDL. This may be a solution when the domain model is small and/or does not change often. The benefits are that you get the cross-interoperability, but you pay with added complexity and a bit of performance (somewhere, somehow the data have to be converted from one model into the other).

However, this becomes cumbersome if the domain model is of a certain complexity.

### Combined solution

Of course, you may also combine both options, e.g. via [MultiplexTransport](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-1915):

```
// the efficient, but Java-only way outlined at the beginning
service MyCoolJavaService {
   binary Foo( 1: binary javaBytes)
}

// miror-model solution

struct EntityOne { ... whatever you need ... }
struct OtherEntity { ... whatever you need ... }
struct ThirdEntity { ... whatever you need ... }

service MyCoolModelService {
   EntityOne Foo( 1: ThirdEntity foo, 2: OtherEntity bar)
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response, we currently thinking about creating our own domain model in thrift to mirror external library classes, it seems to be the most reliable solution at the moment, serialization is fine but may cause issues in future.